# .Net Core 3.1 Adding more than one image per line in the database

Tags: .net, file-io, filestream, asp.net-core-3.1

> I am working on a project and I have a question. I am trying to add
>   more than one image with filestream. I can put the pictures in a
>   multiple format in a folder. I want to add these images to the
>   database in a single(one) column. How can I save these images in a
>   database, side by side. How can I do it?

**Controller**

```
    public IActionResult ImageInsert(ImageViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string uniqueFileName = null;
            if (model.ımageU != null && model.ımageU.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (IFormFile photo in model.ımageU)
                {                     
                    var multiImage = model.ımageU;
                    string uploadFolder = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Image");
                    uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + photo.FileName;
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, uniqueFileName);
                    photo.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                }
                    Images images = new Images
                {
                    Image = uniqueFileName
                    };
                imagemng.InsertImages(images);
            }            
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form method="post" asp-controller="Image" asp-action="ImageInsert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ımageU" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input multiple name="ımageU" type="file" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
                        <label class="custom-file-label">Browse...</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
                @section scripts{
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function () {
                                var fileLabel = $(this).next('.custom-file-label');
                                var files = $(this)[0].files;
                                if (files.length > 1) {
                                    fileLabel.html(files.length + 'files selected');
                                }
                                else if (files.length == 1) {
                                    fileLabel.html(files[0].name);
                                }
                            })
                        });
                    </script>
                }
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**ImageViewModel**

```
public class ImageViewModel
    {
        public List<IFormFile> ımageU { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What's with the code and what's not working?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg                                                                                                               the code is working but we can't record more than 1 in the database, I want to add more than 1 image to a column